# Why do Bleach creators put tons of spoilers at the start and the end of every episode?

Tags: bleach

I'm watching Bleach.

For a long time, it bothered me that the creators put spoilers at the end of each episode.
But it seems understandable. Nowadays, they don't seem to do that, but in the 2000s, it was believed that it made viewers anticipate the next episode (as if they wouldn't wait for it without spoilers). At least that's not surprising.

However, closer to the middle of the series, they started putting a screenshot from the episode with some distortion and a fragment of the opening song. Sometimes, this screenshot spoils what will happen in the episode (in the episode 295, for example). I really don't understand why they do this. It looks and sounds terrible, and on top of that, it doesn't make any sense.

But what annoyed me the most is when they started placing spoilers right from the first seconds of each subsequent episode. Please, explain what's going on in their heads...